# jar-with-dependencies Maven Assembly

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I created a simple Maven project (Packaging type - Jar) that has dependencies on Spring and My Sql library (mysql-connector). When I package this project with `$mvn package` I do get a jar file after successful execution of this command.

I was also trying to include all the dependencies in the output jar file, so I added a 'jar-with-dependencies' assembly descriptor, but as the documentation says:

```
The `jar-with-dependencies` descriptor builds a JAR archive with the contents of the main project jar along with the unpacked contents of all the project’s runtime dependencies.
```

I want to include the dependencies in `JAR` form, not the `unpacked` way. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java cannot load classes from jars in your jar out of the box. You must configure it with project like [one-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) and [maven plugin](http://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help [Maven Shade Plugin:Maven Excecutable Jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html)

Olivier

Answer (score 0):

Vicky is trying to aggregate the jars and this is known as "building-an-aggregate-jar" in Maven's terms. You can find more in Robert's[1] and Artifact Technical Notes'[2] blog.
One discussion[3] that can help as well.

Regards

[1] http://rombertw.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/maven-recipe-building-an-aggregate-jar/

[2] http://blog.artifact-software.com/tech/?p=121

[3] http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Aggregate-POM-for-thirdparty-package-dependencies-not-downloaded-td113927.html